# Wordpress PHP If statement inside assignment

Tags: php, wordpress

Quick simple question, is it possible to do an if statement inside of a php assignment statement so that you can switch what would be assigned?

IE: Inside of a wordpress PHP function that already works

```
$example.='

<div id="test-'.$num.'">
    <a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
</div>';
```

The following doesn't work (gives an IF parse error)

```
$example.='

<div id="test-'.$num.'">
    'if($num == 2)'
        <a href="http://yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>
    'else' <a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
</div>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead you could have done:

```
$aText = ($num == 2) ? '<a href="http://yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>' : '<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>';
$example.='    
<div id="test-'.$num.'">
    '.$aText.'
</div>';
```

Comment: This is a smart way of doing this, I'm going to implement this real quick and see if it works as I expect.

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate the code:-

```
$example.='
<div id="test-'.$num.'">';
    if($num == 2){
       $example.=' <a href="http://yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>';
    }else {
       $example.='<a href="http://google.com">Google</a></div>';
    }
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do it without reassigning the $example.=? The real code is nested a couple of tags down and I would rather see if its possible before going in and separating them. Your way does work though

Comment: in string concatenation - the answer is no, because of we can't use any conditional operator with in string assignment.

Answer (score 0):

check the code:

```
$example.='<div id="test-'.$num.'">';
        if($num == 2)
            $example.= '<a href="http://yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>';
        else 
            $example.='<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>';
    $example.='</div>';
```